# reading txt line by line while its still updating

Tags: .net, vb.net

So basically I have a DLL that is updating a txt file with lines around every second and I want to code a vb.net form that reads it line by line while it's still updating every second but without any repetitions, then put it in a listbox.

I tried to make a *Do Until x Is Nothing* loop but it didn't work. If anyone can help me with anything, please do.

The most important thing would be to not have stuff repeat under any circumstance

Thank you, and if I'm missing something or if my question isn't good please tell me in the comments and I'll edit it!

EDIT: What I tried:

```
Try
        Dim streamreader As StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\ex.txt")
        Dim line As String
        Dim linecount As Integer = 0

        Do
            line = streamreader.ReadLine + linecount

            linecount += 1

            Dim words As String() = line.Split(New String() {":"}, StringSplitOptions.None)

            ListView1.Items.Clear()
            Dim column1 As String = words(1)
            Dim column2 As String = words(2)
            Dim column3 As String = words(3)

            Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
            lvi.Text = column1
            lvi.SubItems.Add(column2)
            lvi.SubItems.Add(column3)
            ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)

        Loop Until line Is Nothing

        streamreader.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

^this is in a timer

Comment: show us what you have so far.

Comment: ok, added it to my post

Comment: You missed [ask] and you need to take the [tour]

Comment: I added the code to my post and I think my question and tags are fine (I think)

Comment: Perhaps you could use a timer to read the file every few seconds and keep a record of how far the file had been read last time so that it knows where to start reading from (if the file has increased in size).

Comment: Ok, I'll try what Andrew said and be back in 5 minutes, thanks!

Comment: ok I updated with what I tried, still doesn't work :(

Comment: I wouldn't suggest the timer approach as it's not sure how many lines per second are written. A way to do it would be to use a dictionnary storing the read lines and when reading a new line checking the dictionnary doesn't have the value. However to put this into play you need to be sure of a few things. **The lines in the file are really seperated by a new line character and that it's impossible to have twice the same line.**

Comment: I'm sorry @Mederic but I don't really understand what you mean, any links to what you're talking about maybe?

Comment: @SoLux very simple: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The problem is in general writting is slower than reading so on a big amount of lines your reader would probabbly catchup to your writter can't you wait until the writter has finished editing the file?

Comment: I'm using a DLL written in C++ to write the txt file and it never actually ends, it just keeps writing

Comment: But then that would be very problematic since after a while your file might end up being over 1G maybe more the problem is we cant know the writting speed or when it ends then your reader will definetly catchup to your writter and then it won't be able to read the next line. I don't think using a sleep would be a good idea on that point so you would have to loop infinitly until a new line is available.

Comment: Yes but I'm having hell of a lot of issues doing that since I don't know much VB.NET, but I'm trying

Comment: Your example probably doesn't work because you just arrive at the moment where the new line isn't written and so it becomes a value of Nothing and thus it exists the loop

Comment: @SoLux your having problem because it's not a good way to approach the problem. reading a file while it's being written is a bad idea in first place

Comment: There's simply no other way to make it communicate to my form, I have to deal with it and make it work. I just have one more question. Is what I tried fully wrong or do I just need to handle it being NULL (empty) and it'll work?

Comment: You could try using a [**`FileSystemWatcher`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) to monitor that file for changes. Keep the `StreamReader` global so you can access it from anywhere and for it to remember its position. Then whenever `FileSystemWatcher.Changed` is raised you read until you get NULL, then you'll just wait for the event to fire again.